# Spring JDBC : unable to get dataSource

Tags: java, spring, maven, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have a spring XML config file called appConfig.xml which contains a datasource bean and another JDBCtemplate to which datasource is passed as an argument:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
</bean>

<bean id="JDBCTemplate" class="com.myprojects.JDBCTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I get an error :

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JDBCTemplate' defined in file [appConfig.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions
>   PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required

From what I see from this error, it is not able to pass dataSource to JDBCTemplate. The logs also says:

> Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I have all dependencies mentioned in pom.xml and I verified that necessary jars for spring are loaded and mysql jdbc connector is also loaded. Any clues on what the issue may be?

I tried a different project where I manually added all spring dependencies and mysql jdbc connector as part of library. It worked fine there. But while trying to include dependencies via pom.xml, I'm facing this issue. So I'm assuming this is to do with some dependency not being pulled in or something. But unable to figure out which one from the error.

Comment: Maybe the 1st part of the stack trace would help. Oh ... also include any "caused by" parts.

Comment: Show us your `JDBCTemplate` class.

Answer (score 3):

It thinks your class `JDBCTemplate` does not have a property named `dataSource`

Perhaps you don't have a public method `setDataSource()` that has a single argument of the right type.

Perhaps it is private.

Perhaps it is spelled wrong.

Comment: I do have the method defined as public void setDataSource(DataSource ds);

Comment: The error says : org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required which means it is not passing the right argument (in this case dataSource itself). I'm not sure what dependency is missed

Comment: Then a log statement or debug breakpoint in the `setDataSource()` method will either happen or not giving you some clues. If you can debug, step through the constructor and setters in the datasource class.

Comment: my bad. It was the result of copy paste of code. I had wrongly assigned dataSource in JDBCTemplate which is why it was taking null.

Comment: Thank you. You are a life saver. I actually was having wrong datasource variable name in the construtor.