# Spring 3 MVC:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required.How to set JdbcTemplate correctly?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-3, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm new to Spring development.And right now,i'm really facing a problem.Here are the code snippets to make you realize my problem clearly.............
Here is my DAO class:

```
public class LoginDaoImpl {

    private DataSource dataSource;              
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public int checkLoginDetails(LoginVo loginVo){
        String sql = "select count(*) from empsctygrp where username=? and password=?";
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);  
        int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,new Object[]{loginVo.getUserName(),loginVo.getPassword()},Integer.class);
        return count;
    }   
}
```

Now here is my Business-Object(BO) class:

```
public class LoginBo {

    LoginDaoImpl loginDaoImpl = new LoginDaoImpl();

    public int checkLoginDetails(LoginVo loginVo){      
        return loginDaoImpl.checkLoginDetails(loginVo);
    }
}
```

Now,here is my dispatcher-servlet xml code:

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@117.194.83.9:1521:XE"/>
  <property name="username" value="system"/>
  <property name="password" value="password1$"/>
</bean>                                     

<bean id="loginDaoImpl" class="com.abhinabyte.dao.LoginDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Now whenever i'm trying to run this on server the following exception is given:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/A] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required] with root cause
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required

Please help me solve this problem.............:(

Comment: Could you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: here is the stacktrace...............

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/A] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
 
 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:135)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:167)

Comment: @Bart can you please tell me in details????????

Comment: ok now I'm doing thuis...

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
       this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
      }
But NullPointer Exception is thrown :(plz help

Comment: You really need to read [the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/)..

Answer (score 0):

Try this in LoginBo class:

```
@Autowired
LoginDaoImpl loginDaoImpl;
```

instead of

`LoginDaoImpl loginDaoImpl = new LoginDaoImpl();`

The problem is that you manually instantiate LoginDaoImpl.

Comment: Do you have `<context:annotation-config/>` in your spring configuration file?

Comment: Ok.I just add it after your suggestion. But it's still throwing nullpointer exception.

Comment: I do believe that I'm making some very silly mistake.Plz check and help me guys....

Comment: @user3159714 Shinichi is right. You're not letting Spring manage your beans. Inject the `loginDaoImpl` bean into a `LoginBo` bean and use that.

Comment: I have already done that using @Autowire annotation as suggested by him.But it's now throwing NullPointer Exception.

Comment: How do you instantiate LoginBo? Could you share your spring configuration file?

Comment: `LoginBo loginBo = new LoginBo();` is one of the causes of the problem.  Objects that are instantiated using the "new" keyword are not managed by Spring Framework. I would recommend reading the reference manual [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) for solid understanding of Spring Framework's IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate that beans that will suffer IoC. Like

```
@Bean public class LoginDAOImpl { @Inject DataSource dataSource;......}
```

You set up in spring context this beans, but, you're not using them.

OBS:

When I use the JDBCTemplate I configure de IoC of JDBC like

```
<bean id="dataSourcePerfil" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${br.com.dao.jdbc.driver}" /> 
    <property name="url" value="${br.com.dao.jdbc.url}" /> 
    <property name="username" value="${br.com.dao.jdbc.user}" /> 
    <property name="password" value="${br.com.dao.jdbc.pass}" /> 
</bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSourcePerfil" />
</bean>
```

then.... after at all

```
@Bean
```

public class LoginDAOImpl {

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


@Override
public List<ClienteReport> getClientes() {
    return Collections<ClienteReport>. emptyList();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and could not find a comprehensive answer on the web, so I decided to post one here for anyone else, or for future me.

I'm still learning so if you think I have made a mistake below, please feel free to edit.

**Summary:**

- Include `<integration:annotation-config/> <context:component-scan base-package="myproject"/>` in your servlet to pick up annotations
- Configure JUnit tests with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @ContextConfiguration("file:WEB-INF/FinanceImportTool-servlet.xml")`
- Don't autowire `dataSource` or `jdbcTemplate` if these fields are already provided by a parent class e.g. `StoredProcedure`
- Don't use `new()` as this initializes classes outside the applicationContext
- Beware of using properties in your constructor which have not yet been set - obvious but embarrassingly easy to do

---

My original class (now altered):

```
public class MyDAOImpl extends StoredProcedure implements MyDAO {
    private static final String SPROC_NAME = "dbo.MySP";    

    public MyDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, SPROC_NAME); 
        // ...declared parameters...
        compile();
    }
}
```

MyProject-servlet.xml file (only relevant bits included):

```
<!-- Used by Spring to pick up annotations -->
<integration:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="myproject"/>

<bean id="MyDAOBean" class="myproject.dao.MyDAOImpl" >
    <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
</bean>

<!-- properties stored in a separate file -->
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
    <property name="databaseName" value="${myDataSource.dbname}" />
    <property name="serverName" value="${myDataSource.svrname}" />
    <!-- also loaded portNumber, user, password, selectMethod -->
</bean>
```

---

**Error: property 'dataSource' is required, or NullPointerException (1)**

Other answers say make sure you have passed `dataSource` as a `<property>` for your bean in the servlet, etc.

I think @Abhinabyte the OP needed to annotate his `setDataSource()` method with `@Annotation`, and use `<integration:annotation-config/> <context:component-scan base-package="myproject"/>` in his servlet to successfully pass in `dataSource` as a dependency to `LoginDaoImpl`.

In my case, I tried adding 'dataSource' as a property and autowiring it. The "dataSource is required" error message became a NullPointerException error.

I realised after far too long that `MyDAOImpl` extends `StoredProcedure`.

`dataSource` was already a property of `StoredProcedure`. By having a `dataSource` property for `MyDAOImpl`, the autowiring was not picking up and setting the `dataSource` property of `StoredProcedure`, which left `dataSource` for `StoredProcedure` as null.

This was not picked up when I tested the value of `MyDAOImpl.dataSource`, as of course by now I had added a MyDAOImpl.dataSource field that had been autowired successfully. However the `compile()` method inherited from `StoredProcedure` used `StoredProcedure.dataSource`.

Therefore I didn't need `public DataSource dataSource;` property in `MyDAOImpl` class. I just needed to use the `StoredProcedure` constructor with `super(dataSource, sql);`  in the constructor for `MyDAOImpl`.

I also didn't need a `MyDAOImpl.jdbcTemplate` property. It was set automatically by using the `StoredProcedure(dataSource, sql)` constructor.

---

**Error: NullPointerException (2)**

I had been using this constructor:

```
private static final String SPROC_NAME = "dbo.MySP";

public MyDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource, SPROC_NAME);
}
```

This caused a `NullPointerException` because `SPROC_NAME` had not been initialized before it was used in the constructor (yes I know, rookie error). To solve this, I passed in `sql` as a constructor-arg in the servlet.

---

**Error: [same error message appeared when I had changed file name]**

The applicationContext was referring to the bin/ instances of my beans and classes. I had to delete bin/ and rebuild the project.

---

**My new class:**

```
   public class MyDAOImpl extends StoredProcedure implements MyDAO {

   @Autowired // Necessary to prevent error 'no default constructor found'
   public MyDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource, String sql) {
       super(dataSource, sql);
        // ...declared parameters...
        compile();
   }
```

**New MyProject-servlet.xml file** (only relevant bits included):

```
<!-- Used by Spring to pick up annotations -->
<integration:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="myproject"/>

<bean id="myDAOBean" class="org.gosh.financeimport.dao.MyDAOImpl" >
    <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="reDataSource"/>
    <constructor-arg name="sql" value="dbo.MySP" />
</bean>

<!-- properties stored in a separate file -->
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
    <property name="databaseName" value="${myDataSource.dbname}" />
    <property name="serverName" value="${myDataSource.svrname}" />
    <!-- also loaded portNumber, user, password, selectMethod -->
</bean>
```

---

Helpful places:

If you can get past the rage, [this answer](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/48919-datasource-problem-illegalargumentexception-property-datasource-is-required) on Spring forums might help too

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21679282/2294676) gives a broad introduction to Spring configuration

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841519/2294676) has simple but useful suggestions